# How to import Plutus.Contracts.Currency

Tags: smart-contract

I am trying to build an application that will make use of function **mintContract** under **Plutus.Contracts.Currency**, but i have difficulty importing this module. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can import it as follows as then use it with `Cur.mintContract`.

```
import Plutus.Contracts.Currency qualified as Cur
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But maybe i should have been more explicit on what i've tried before. I did try "import Plutus.Contracts.Currency qualified as XXX", but it said "Could not find module `Plutus.Contracts.Currency'". I tried this on my local playground and https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/, it shows the same error message.

I am not sure if it is due to the playground not being up-to-date.

Comment: Hey, it seems at the end i can get around with mintContract with singleton and mustMintValue and achieve the same purpose.